# How to make Android java global string variable?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, global-variables

How do I make global string variable on android-java, and how to access it on diffrent activity?

Answer (score 1):

In res>values>strings.xml, add this global variable:

```
<string name="path">http://192.168.3.18</string>
```

Then in your activity, you can use

```
String path = getString(R.string.path);
```

to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't make global string variables in Android. What you should do is to use a resource file. Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is to store the string in somewhere in the app and wherever you need it recover it.

You can use SharedPreferences.

Store it:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("CoolPreferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("StringName", "StringValue");
// Commit the edits!
editor.commit();
```

Recover it:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("CoolPreferences", 0);
String silent = settings.getString("StringName", "DefaultValueIfNotExists");
```

You need a Context like and Activity to call getSharedPreferences()